# Unable to open .pem file in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

I am beginner in programming, for a school project i was building an android application to turn on/off LED using esp 32 and AWS IOT. I am using mqtt_client 9.6.4, when i run the aws_iot.dart example i am able to connect to AWS IOT and perform the action using the same script. when i use the same code in a flutter i get the following error message in my debug console, E/flutter (15280): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'AmazonRootCA1.pem' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

How can this be resolved?

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import 'lib/mqtt_server_client.dart';
import 'lib/mqtt_client.dart';
import 'package:pem/pem.dart';

var switch1 = 0;

Future<int> main() async {
  const url = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com';

  const port = 8883;

  const clientId = 'Flutter';

 
  final client = MqttServerClient.withPort(url, clientId, port);

 
  client.secure = true;

  client.keepAlivePeriod = 20;
  
  client.setProtocolV311();

  client.logging(on: true);

  final context = SecurityContext.defaultContext;

  context.setClientAuthorities('AmazonRootCA1.pem');

  context.useCertificateChain('certificate.pem.crt');

  context.usePrivateKey('private.pem.key');


  client.securityContext = context;

  final connMess =
      MqttConnectMessage().withClientIdentifier(clientId).startClean();
  client.connectionMessage = connMess;

  
  try {
    print('MQTT client connecting to AWS IoT....');
    await client.connect();
  } on Exception catch (e) {
    print('MQTT client exception - $e');
    client.disconnect();
  }

  if (client.connectionStatus!.state == MqttConnectionState.connected) {
    print('MQTT client connected to AWS IoT');

    
    const topic = 'esp32/relay1';
    const topic2 = 'esp32/relay2';
    final builder = MqttClientPayloadBuilder();
    builder.addString('{\"status\":\"0\"}');
    
    client.publishMessage(topic, MqttQos.atLeastOnce, builder.payload!);

    
    client.subscribe(topic2, MqttQos.atLeastOnce);
    
    client.updates!.listen((List<MqttReceivedMessage<MqttMessage>> c) {
      final recMess = c[0].payload as MqttPublishMessage;
      final pt =
          MqttPublishPayload.bytesToStringAsString(recMess.payload.message);
      print(
          'EXAMPLE::Change notification:: topic is <${c[0].topic}>, payload is <-- $pt -->');
      print('');
    });
  } else {
    print(
        'ERROR MQTT client connection failed - disconnecting, state is ${client.connectionStatus!.state}');
    client.disconnect();
  }

  print('Sleeping....');
  await MqttUtilities.asyncSleep(60);

  print('Disconnecting');
  client.disconnect();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try using the Bytes variants of the `SecurityContext` methods.

First, you will need to make sure that the files you are referencing are defined in your `pubspec.yaml` file:

```yaml
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/AmazonRootCA1.pem # assuming you placed these files in a folder called assets
    - assets/certificate.pem.crt
    - assets/private.pem.key
```

This will ensure that the files are packaged with the app such that you can load them using `rootBundle`.

Then in your code load the files using `rootBundle` and pass the data to the `SecurityContext` as bytes.

```dart
  final context = SecurityContext.defaultContext;

  final clientAuthorities = await rootBundle.load('assets/AmazonRootCA1.pem');
  context.setClientAuthoritiesBytes(clientAuthorities.buffer.asUint8List());

  final certificateChain = await rootBundle.load('assets/certificate.pem.crt');
  context.useCertificateChainBytes(certificateChain.buffer.asUint8List());

  final privateKey = await rootBundle.load('assets/private.pem.key');
  context.usePrivateKeyBytes(privateKey.buffer.asUint8List());
```

As an aside, I'm a little confused by why your main method in a flutter project doesn't call `runApp`, and instead returns an `int`. But if you do use the code above in the main method of a flutter app, you may need to call `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` in `main` prior to using `rootBundle.load`.

Comment: The posted code is a pure Dart test harness (i.e. command line app). (Credit to the poster for trying stuff in a test harness.) The question doesn't make clear that they are then trying to port the working command line code over to Flutter, and should likely be making use of assets (as you rightly point out).